# Assigning functions as variables for a finite state machine in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm experimenting with making games in python and ran into the problem of having an object switch states depending on an action in the game.

I find that the best way of doing this is most likely to have some kind of way to define a function (the object's state) as a variable and give the object a state depending on an action. Unfortunately, I am not sure if this is possible, or possibly there is a concept that which I have yet to learn when it comes to this topic. If anyone could provide a solution to my problem or simply point me in the direction to learn of a way to deal with the problem.

Is there a way to associate some functions/methods to names and avoid multiple `if` statements ?

```
class stateUser:

    def __init__(self,state):
        self.state = state

    def executeState(self):
        if self.state == "Print Something":
            self.printSomething()
        elif self.state == "Not Print Something":
            self.dontPrint()
        else:
            self.notUnderstand()
        '''
            would like this function to simply call
            a function that is defined as the object's state,
            instead of using a bunch of if statements
        '''

    def printSomething(self):
        print("Something")

    def dontPrint(self):
        print("No")

    def notUnderstand(self):
        print("I didn't understand that")

runner = stateUser(None)
a = True
while a:
    runner.state = input("Enter the state you would like to change to\n")

    runner.executeState()
```

The above code is obviously not a direct snippet from the game project I am making, but rather just something I typed up that is very similar in situation. Any comments or solutions will be welcomed gratefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a dict to store all actions and the matching functions/methods.

Then you only have to use `dict.get()` to find the matching action given by user or use the default `self.notUnderstand` (passed as second parameter):

The dict structure allows to store functions as references, without `()`, so you just have to add these brackets on the result `action`. (or add it directly 
to `self.actions.get(self.state, self.notUnderstand)()` to save a line).

```
class stateUser:

    def __init__(self,state):
        self.state = state
        self.actions = {
            'printSomething': self.printSomething,
            'Not Print Something': self.dontPrint,
        }

    def executeState(self):
        action = self.actions.get(self.state, self.notUnderstand)
        action()
```

---

Another advantage is that you can use the keys of this dict to offer the choices to user :

```
while a:
    runner.state = input("Enter the state you would like to change to\n"+
                         ' - '.join(runner.actions.keys()))

    runner.executeState()

#>>> Enter the state you would like to change to
#printSomething - Not Print Something
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, thank you for creating a smaller snippet, it helps make the problem easier to manage.

You essentially are looking to "map" a state to an action. Dictionaries are perfect for this use case. Create a dictionary/mapping where the "keys" are the states, and then "action" is the actual function. Just use that mapping to execute the correct function as needed.

A simple example as follows:

```
class stateUser:

    def __init__(self,state):
        self.state = state

    def executeState(self):
        map_state_to_action = {
                "Print Something": self.printSomething,  # note that no brackets were used. 
                "Not Print Something": self.dontPrint,  # we are interested in the function itself.
                }
        #a dict.get takes a key, returns the value if the key is present in the dict, or returns the other argument if key was not found.
        map_state_to_action.get(self.state, self.notUnderstand)()  # note the brackets at the end to call the func.        

    def printSomething(self):
        print("Something")

    def dontPrint(self):
        print("No")

    def notUnderstand(self):
        print("I didn't understand that")

runner = stateUser(None)
a = True
while a: #could just change this to while True:
    runner.state = input("Enter the state you would like to change to\n")

    runner.executeState()
```

Note that you will have to establish the link between a state and the desired action *somewhere*, unless rather than setting a state you directly called the action during a game runtime.